# How to disable insert-mode popup-menu mappings?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I'd like to disable the popup menu scroll mappings `<C-n>` and `<C-p>`, so that I can use `<C-j>` and `<C-k>` instead. However, when I enter

```
imap <C-p> <Nop>
imap <C-n> <Nop>
```

the mappings are still active! How do I disable or override them permanently? Is it not possible?

To be clear, when I call `:verb imap <C-p>` I see

```
i  <C-P>         <Nop>
```

yet the shortcut still works.

---

**Update**: Here is the output of `:version`, if that helps:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep 20 2018 03:49:43)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-400
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +conceal           +folding           +menu              +packages          -sun_workshop      +visual
+arabic            +cryptv            -footer            +mksession         +path_extra        +syntax            +visualextra
+autocmd           +cscope            +fork()            +modify_fname      +perl              +tag_binary        +viminfo
+autochdir         +cursorbind        -gettext           +mouse             +persistent_undo   +tag_old_static    +vreplace
-autoservername    +cursorshape       -hangul_input      -mouseshape        +postscript        -tag_any_white     +wildignore
-balloon_eval      +dialog_con        +iconv             +mouse_dec         +printer           -tcl               +wildmenu
+balloon_eval_term +diff              +insert_expand     -mouse_gpm         +profile           +termguicolors     +windows
-browse            +digraphs          +job               -mouse_jsbterm     -python            +terminal          +writebackup
++builtin_terms    -dnd               +jumplist          +mouse_netterm     +python3           +terminfo          -X11
+byte_offset       -ebcdic            +keymap            +mouse_sgr         +quickfix          +termresponse      -xfontset
+channel           +emacs_tags        +lambda            -mouse_sysmouse    +reltime           +textobjects       -xim
+cindent           +eval              +langmap           +mouse_urxvt       +rightleft         +timers            -xpm
-clientserver      +ex_extra          +libcall           +mouse_xterm       +ruby              +title             -xsmp
+clipboard         +extra_search      +linebreak         +multi_byte        +scrollbind        -toolbar           -xterm_clipboard
+cmdline_compl     +farsi             +lispindent        +multi_lang        +signs             +user_commands     -xterm_save
+cmdline_hist      +file_in_path      +listcmds          -mzscheme          +smartindent       +vartabs
+cmdline_info      +find_in_path      +localmap          +netbeans_intg     +startuptime       +vertsplit
+comments          +float             +lua               +num64             +statusline        +virtualedit
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -
L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lncurses -liconv -framework AppKit  -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.3 -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -fstack-protector-
strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.28.0/lib/perl5/5.28.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc  -L/usr/local/opt/
python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin -lpython3.7m -framework CoreFoundation  -lruby.2.5.1 -lobjc
```

Comment: Are you running the check on the same buffer that ignore the noop? Maybe a plugin or language script is resetting the auto complete? Try with Vim -u NONE.

Comment: **Really** weird: running `vim -u NONE` and unmapping the keys as above (or as in statox's answer) still does not disable them; they still bring up/scroll the popup menu. Maybe it's somehow baked into vim? But I thought nothing was baked in.

Comment: Just tried the `imap` commands on my setup and it works (disabling the autocomplete menu) normally. Try using `:verbose map` and `:verbose map!` to list your mappings and find the offending configuration.

Comment: Actually I've think of something else. Maybe your terminal setup is wrong and you managed to add the autocomplete mappings to a different key sequence. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for these help topics:

- [`:h :map-<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap-%3cexpr%3e)
- [`:h pumvisible()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#pumvisible%28%29)

And the resulting mappings should be like this:

```
inoremap <expr> <C-n> pumvisible() ? "" : "\<C-n>"
inoremap <expr> <C-j> pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" : "\<C-j>"

inoremap <expr> <C-p> pumvisible() ? "" : "\<C-p>"
inoremap <expr> <C-k> pumvisible() ? "\<C-p>" : "\<C-k>"
```

`pumvisible()` returns a boolean indication if the completion menu is on or not. The `<expr>` tag of the mappings allows to execute vimscript expressions.

So we remap `<C-n>` so that is acts as itself when the completion menu is off and to do nothing when we are in the completion menu. Reciprocally we remap `<C-j>` to act like `<C-n>` when the completion menu is out and as itself when it's not.

Note that you should not remap `<C-j>` inconditionnaly because it is [equivalent to `<CR>`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5233/1841)

The mappings for `<C-p>` and `<C-k>` follow the same idea.

---

Also, as often, you forgot the `nore` part of the `imap` command which is a [bad practice](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10130/1841).

Comment: Thanks, but this still fails to disable those keys. Does it work for you? I'm aware of the `pumvisible()` command and `<expr>` mappings. I also used `imap` because it was just a mapping to a `<Nop>`..... and if you've remapped `<Nop>` (if that's even possible), you've got bigger problems than accidental recursion. Anyway I would have assumed by default that insert mode mappings work whether or not the popup menu is visible so didn't think that was the issue.

Comment: @LukeDavis It does work for me (I just tested it again) so it's really strange that it doesn't work for you. About the non recursive mapping I just said that because a lot of new vimmer don't know what it is and we had a lot of questions about that, but indeed it is not mandatory here, just a best practice.

Comment: Downvoted because using expression shouldn't make any difference, the OP's question is clearly about his mapping not working as expected.

Comment: Good job @Spidey :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce your behavior. I'm suspecting that you have other mappings for the autocomplete menu and that your `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` sequences are not being used.

To check that try the following command:

`:verbose imap ^V^N`

Where `^V` is Ctrl-V and `^N` is Ctrl-N. This will insert the literal key sequence that Vim is receiving when pressing Ctrl-N on your setup. I'm guessing that this and `^V^P` are being remapped to the autocomplete functions (`<C-n>` and `<C-p>`) as well.

Comment: This is closer to the answer! With `vim -u NONE`, using `:imap <C-n> <Nop>`  fails, but `:imap ^V^N` succeeds in disabling popup scrolling. It seems that **my copy of vim itself** interprets the literal sequences `^N` and `^P` as the popup-menu scrolling commands. However, even weirder, when I run **without**  `-u NONE`, vim **no longer sees any difference** between the `<C-n>` and `^N` maps (in the former case, running `:imap <C-n>` and `:imap ^V^N` returned different results). So, in my working setup, I cannot directly remap the literal `^N`. How could this be? Some obscure setting?

Comment: This might be related to how Vim detects your terminal. Which terminal are you using?