# How to enter insert mode on the next line without creating a new line?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

If my cursor is at position * below, how can I enter insert mode at the beginning of the next line *without* creating a newline? `o` does what I want, except that it adds an additional unwanted line into the block that I then have to delete.

```
*let(:foo) do

 end
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no special command for this. Use `ji` maybe followed by `<C-T>` to get the indent. See `:help i_CTRL-T`. Maybe better: `jA` in case there are already leading spaces/tab.

Answer (score 3):

As Ralf said in the comments, there is no built-in command that does this. I would recommend using either `ji`, `jI`, or `jA` for this purpose, since those are all only two keys, and they're fairly normal vim idioms.

If you'd really like to do this with a single keystroke, you could always overwrite the `o` command to not make a newline. To do this, add *one of* the following lines to your `.vimrc` (depending on which behavior you want):

```
" Enter insert mode at the beginning of the next line
nnoremap o j0i

" Enter insert mode at the end of the next line
nnoremap o jA

" Enter insert mode at the first non-whitespace character
nnoremap o jI
```

(Note that the lines starting with `"` are just comments)

Unfortunately, this overwrites `o` which I think is a very useful command. Normally, to add your own shortcuts without overwriting the default ones, it's standard to use `<leader>`. However in this case, something like

```
nnoremap <leader>o ji
```

would be pretty pointless since it's not any shorter than just manually doing it with `ji`

Comment: Definitely entering overkill land here but you could make it shorter than the original command by picking a control+key combo that's either unmapped or mapped to something you don't use. `Ctrl-J` is just a synonym for `j` so there's that...

Comment: @blayer Unfortunately, `<C-j>` can be hard to map to sometimes because the terminal interprets it differently.

Comment: I use all manner of *nix and Win machines and have a <C-J> map...not once have I had an issue. Test it, sure, but it's pretty safe in my experience. Otherwise it's likely something that can be resolved (e.g. terminal configuration, disable a readline bind, etc.). Worst case, use `Ctrl-whatever` instead. :)

Comment: @BLayer See [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5255/2920) I use GVim, and it generally works pretty well for me, but I've definitely had some problems in various terminal emulators.

Comment: I read that and said "Aha, Insert mode must be the difference...I don't use Ctrl-J there." But, alas, even with that everything still works fine for me on Win/gVIm, Cygwin and one instance of Linux I tried. Anyways, I don't mean to suggest that everyone else is imagining things! It's certainly worth pointing out as you've done. Cheers.