# Mapping breaks built-in Vim command?

Tags: key-bindings

In Vim the commands `<C-o>` and `<C-i>` move backwards and forwards through the jump list.

```
:h CTRL-I
```

I noticed that `<Tab>` is the alternative command you can use instead of `<C-i>` and this leads me to my question...

I have the following mapping defined in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <Tab> gt
```

It works fine, in that if I press `<Tab>` and there are tabs open, it will iterate through the list of tabs.

But I then noticed that `<C-i>` stops working and instead is mapped to my new mapping behaviour...

```
:verbose map <C-i>
```

...would show the line in my `.vimrc` where I had defined the updated `Tab` mapping.

How can I prevent `<C-i>` from being remapped to where I'm now mapping `Tab` to?

I already use `nnoremap` so `<Tab>` doesn't get expanded back to the original `<C-i>` jump list behaviour, and so I'm not sure how to prevent that with `<C-i>` unless I try maybe doing something weird like `nnoremap <C-i> <C-i>` (which doesn't work btw as I tried it).

> Note: if I comment out my new map `nnoremap <Tab> gt` and restart Vim the `<C-i>` behaviour goes back to normal, and there's no longer a mapping against it (e.g. `:verbose map <C-i>` returns nothing).

Comment: Tab is a synonym of C-i. They produce the same escape sequence for terminals afair.

Comment: Have a look at an [ascii table](http://ascii-table.com/control-chars.php). `CTRL-I` is the **same** as `<Tab>`.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate because we have a lot of similar question [ex 1](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3119/1841), [ex 2](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5233/1841), [ex 3](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3225/1841), [ex 4](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4290/1841) and I tried to make something more generic [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7722/1841)